# Hadoop Error: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop

So, after seeing the a percent or so of running the job I get an error that says, "Error: Java heap space" and then something along the lines of, "Application container killed"

I am literally running an empty map and reduce job. However, the job does take in an input that is, roughly, about 100 gigs. For whatever reason, I run out of heap space. Although the job does nothing.

I am using default configurations and it's on a single machine. It is running on hadoop version 2.2 and ubuntu. The machine has 4 gigs of ram.

Thanks!

//Note
Got it figured out.
Turns out I was setting the configuration to have a different terminating token/string. The format of the data had changed, so that token/string no longer existed. So it was trying to send all 100gigs into ram for one key.

Comment: "So, after seeing the a percent or so of running the job" did you mean this ? Are you using a identity mapper and reducer or have you coded a "empty" mapper and reducer ?

Comment: Well apparently it does something.  You should post all of your code (driver and mapper/reducer if applicable).

Comment: Good work figuring it out.  You should post your edit as an answer for the next person who has the same question.